# Checkbox is not getting checked using knockout js?

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

In payment method, I am adding one more option i.e Store Credit.
Store Credit uses checkbox field.

Test/Payment/view/frontend/web/template/payment/storecredits.html

```
  <div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
<div class="payment-method-title field choice">
    <input type="checkbox"
           name="payment[method]"
           class="radio"
           data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()"/>
    <label data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}" class="label"><span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span></label>
</div> 
</div>
```

app/code/Test/Payment/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/storecredits-method.js

```
define(
[
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default'
],
function (Component) {
    'use strict';
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Test_Payment/payment/storecredits'
        },
        getMailingAddress: function () {
            return window.checkoutConfig.payment.checkmo.mailingAddress;
        },
        selectPaymentMethod: function () {
            alert(jQuery("#storecredits").is("checked")); exit;

        },
    });
}
);
```